# Will I lose payments on a mining share in the time it takes to sync?

Tags: wallet

I bought a mining share a couple months ago from Bitcoop, downloaded the wallet that they suggested, and the wallet has taken this long to sync. The first mining payout was a few weeks ago.

Will I get that payment or is it lost?

Answer (score 2):

You will get that payment. Your wallet does not need to be online or synchronized to receive funds, only to do anything with them. (I'm assuming you're using Bitcoin-qt or something similar, I don't know what that vendor recommended or what you've done.)

However, the client shouldn't take months to sync, so this could indicate there is some problem.